# Excerpt Is Disappeared

Tags: read-more, excerpt

My theme automatically assign before of `<!--more-->` tags, as excerpt.And showing excerpt on home page. Now i want to add Google Adsense after `<!-- more -->` code. I'm wrote this function and add it to functions.php

```
function google_adsense($content)
{
    if(is_single())
    {
        global $post;
        $thePostID = $post->ID;
        $more_span = '<span id="more-' .$thePostID.'"></span>' ;
        return str_replace($more_span, $more_span . " " . google_reklam_ekle(), $content);
    }
}
function google_reklam_ekle()
{
    return "<!-- Google Adsense -->
<script type=\"text/javascript\"><!--
google_ad_client = \"ca-pub-9792205570091420\";
/* teknoblogo-yazi-alaninda */
google_ad_slot = \"0917868905\";
google_ad_width = 468;
google_ad_height = 60;
//-->
</script>
<script type=\"text/javascript\"
src=\"http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js\">
</script>
<!-- bit Google Adsense -->";
}
add_filter('the_content', 'google_adsense');
```

Now excerpts isn't disappering excerpts. When i remove this functions, they're appearing again.

In single page, code is working very well. You can check my blog posts. http://www.teknoblogo.com . There is an Adsense Ads after  tag. But before add this Adsense codes, my post's first part (i mean before of `<!--more-->` tag) appearing .

Can you give an idea to me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have forgotten to return the unaltered $content if this is not a single post:

```
function google_adsense($content) {     
  if(is_single())     
  {         
   global $post;         
   $thePostID = $post->ID;         
   $more_span = '<span id="more-' .$thePostID.'"></span>' ;         
   return str_replace($more_span, $more_span . " " . google_reklam_ekle(), $content);     
   } else { 
   return $content; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Haha! We both arrived at the same conclusion and posted it at nearly the same time!

Comment: Opps you right !!! I working on this about an hour. And i couldn't found this ! Haha ! Thank you Michael and Sardine :)

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured this out. The problem, I believe, is that you specify your function to run only on single posts via `is_single()`. When it is not a single post, you return no content, therefore your content vanishes! Try this:

```
function google_adsense($content)
{
    if(is_single())
    {
        global $post;
        $thePostID = $post->ID;
        $more_span = '<span id="more-' .$thePostID.'"></span>' ;
        return str_replace($more_span, $more_span . " " . google_reklam_ekle(), $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

I think this will fix your vanishing content problem! It did when I ran your functions on my dev site.